# How to have module consumer define type in Elm

Tags: types, elm

I've created a table module in my Elm project.

Each column has a getter function that defines how they retrieve data from the Records that model the rows.

So a Row could look something like:

```
{ name = "bananas"
, price = 5
}
```

and the columns could look like this:

```
[ { title = "Item Name"
  , get = .name
  }
, { title = "Price in pennies"
  , get = .price >> (*) 100 >> toString
  }
]
```

This means the type annotation for the column `get` function is:
`Row -> String`

The problem I have is that I want to make this table module a reusable component for other projects that have their own "Row" type. How do I allow the consumer of the module to specify the Row type alias without removing all my type annotations?

I'm quite new to Elm so sorry if the wording in my question is off.

Comment: Take a look at [`evancz/elm-sortable-table`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/evancz/elm-sortable-table/latest) which offers some abstractions for dealing with this. There is a `Column` type which lets you create custom configurations per type in order to build your rendered value. [Here is an example setting up that configuration](https://github.com/evancz/elm-sortable-table/blob/master/examples/1-presidents.elm#L83-L94)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using your own type, `Row`, you can introduce a type variable (often `a`, but any lower-case name will work, e.g. `data` in [elm-sortable-table](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/evancz/elm-sortable-table/latest))

You can then create something like this:

```
type alias Column a =
    { get : a -> String
    , title : String
    }

type alias Columns a =
    List (Column a)

viewTable : Columns a -> List a -> Html msg
```